# Making sense of 'Floppy' Structures on Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, smooth-manifolds, mathematical-physics, symplectic-geometry

Roger Penrose in his book "The Road to Reality" (Section 14.8 - Symplectic Manifolds) ***loosely*** defines a *"floppy" structure* to be one which if we apply two variants of it on two copies of the same manifold, the two manifolds are locally isomorphic (and thus locally indistinguishable from one another). The example he brings is that of two symplectic manifolds with the same dimension and signature. I think what he is referring to (although he does not make it explicit) is [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem) which again asserts that two symplectic manifolds of the same dimension are locally isomorphic (more accurately: [symplectomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectomorphism)).

In his exact words and I quote:

> The local structure of a symplectic manifold is an example of what
> might be called a ‘Floppy’ structure. There is, for example, no notion
> of curvature for a symplectic manifold, which might serve to
> distinguish one symplectic manifold from another, locally. If we have
> two real symplectic manifolds of the same dimension (and the same
> ‘signature’, cf. §13.10), then they are locally completely identical
> (in the sense that for any point p in one manifold and any point q in
> the other, there are open sets of p and q that are identical). This
> is in stark contrast with the case of (pseudo-) Riemannian manifolds,
> or manifolds in which merely a connection is specified. In those
> cases, the curvature tensor (and, for example, its various covariant
> derivatives) defines some distinguishing local structure which is
> likely to be different for different such manifolds.

This makes sense to me. Then he goes on to describe two more examples of manifolds one of which is floppy while the other isn't. In particular he makes the following two claims:

1. Let $M_1$ be a real manifold with a nowhere vanishing vector field $F$ on it. Then $M_1$ is a floppy manifold.
2. In contrast, let $M_2$ be a real manifold with two general vector fields. Then $M_2$ is NOT a floppy manifold

**Question 1:** For the 1st part, I think the family of tori would be a good place to start since assigning a (smooth) nowhere vanishing vector field is always possible. I can also see how we can use $F$ to define a global frame on the entire $M_1$ starting by setting $\partial_1 := F \neq 0$ etc. However, in what sense are all tori (with $F$) locally indistinguishable? For example, shouldn't we able to (locally) distinguish a torus with circular cross sections versus one with elliptical just by looking at the difference in curvatures between a circle and an ellipse?

**Question 2:** Now to his second claim. First of all, what do you think he means by "general" vector fields? Am I right to assume that they are linearly independent and by extension neither one of these can be anywhere vanishing (as this would violate independence)? And how does the existence of the second field makes them distinguishable?

Comment: Your opening phrase regarding "floppy structure on 2 different manifold" seems off. Floppiness is a property of the structure itself, not of the manifold which supports the structure. Symplectic structures are floppy: a symplectic structure *on any $n$ manifold* is locally isomorphic at every point to the standard symplectic structure on $\mathbb R^n$ (yes, that is Darboux's theorem).

Comment: Nonvanishing vector fields are floppy: a nonvanishing vector field *on any $n$-manifold* is locally isomorphic at every point to a coordinate vector field on $\mathbb R^n$. So your question 1 regarding the torus is irrelevant. Yes, the torus does have nonvanishing vector fields, and each of them is locally isomorphic to a coordinate vector field on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Whether or not a given $n$-manifold $M$ has a nonvanishing vector field is an interesting question, but *not* with regard to floppiness: any nonvanishing vector field that does happen to exist on $M$ is locally isomorphic to a coordinate vector field on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for your comment. This exactly why I posted this question, to clarify the definition. For example, is it just the structure or the manifold PLUS the structure? For example, what am I to make of the following statement (taken verbatim from Penrose): "A real manifold with two general vector fields on it would be floppy". Straightforward grammar suggests that the floppiness refers to the manifold. When paired with contexts it seems to refer to the structure PLUS the manifold.

Comment: Then there is his other (verbatim) statement: "One such example [of a floppy structure] would be a real manifold with a nowhere vanishing vector field on it". Again, does he include the manifold to the structure? If not, why can't he simply skip the word manifold altogether and just say "a vanishing vector field"?

Comment: I disagree with your parsing of that verbatim sentence: the thing whose floppiness is being asserted is "a real manifold with two general vector fields", not just "a real manifold". (I am skeptical of that sentence because, as explained in the answer of @JasonDeVito, the Lie bracket is an invariant of a pair of nonvanishing vector fields on a manifold).

Comment: Regarding Penrose's choice of wording and why he doesn't skip the word "manifold" altogether, well, you'll have to ask him. Having said that, an actual vector field is an object defined on an actual manifold, and the rigorous statement of floppiness of nonvanishing vector fields is what I said in my earlier comment.

Comment: @Lee Mosher. Thank you again. My point was that from the context it seems like Penrose considers the manifold to be part of the whole structure (Even when I talk about the tori, I mean the tori PLUS their vector fields, not the manifolds alone). In any case, the wording used here is largely Penrose's not mine. Moreover, I think we are all clear that the "stuff" (here vector fields) defined on the manifold are at the very least the core of the definition if not the entire definition.

Comment: @LeeMosher:  Minor correction to what you wrote above.  As far as I can tell (I don't have a copy of Penrose's book availabe), Penrose asserts that a manifold with two vector fields is *not* floppy, not that it is floppy.  This is consistent with my answer below.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I think that was me, and indeed it was a typo. I can confirm that Penrose asserts that a manifold with two vector fields is not floppy. Thank you for catching it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 1:  I think Penrose is thinking of manifolds (which are floppy) as opposed to Riemannian manifolds (which are not).  Specifically, the idea of a torus having a cross sectional circle vs a cross sectional ellipse is implicitly viewing tori as Riemannian manifolds, not as plain manifolds.

The sense in which a manifold with vector field is floppy is the following:

> Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and $V$ is a smooth vector field on $M$ with $V(p)\neq 0$ for some $p\in M$.  Then there is a chart $U$ containing $p$ for which $V$ is a coordinate vector field.

(See, e.g., [Theorem 2.1 of these notes](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/veccoord.pdf))

Question 2:  I'm not exactly sure what Penrose means by "general", but his comment certainly applies to linearly independent vector fields.  Specifically, given linearly independent vector fields $V_1$ and $V_2$ on (a neighborhood in) a manifold, one can ask whether or not there is a single chart where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are both coordinate vector fields.

In general, the Lie bracket $[V_1,V_2]$ measures the obstruction to this.  That is, if $[V_1,V_2] = 0$, then the answer is yes, while if the bracket is non-zero, the answer is no.

Comment: As someone who is *not* a symplectic geometer, the floppiness has always seemed artificial to me.  Namely the condition $d\omega = 0$ seems analogous to me of saying "flat" in Riemannian geometry.  And flat Riemannian manifolds *are* floppy.  I am totally unaware of any study of "fake-sympletic" forms where the closed assumption is dropped.

Comment: This is helpful thanks. Since I am not a differential geometer, can you perhaps say a bit more about what is the notion of "sameness" for the tori then? In what way are two tori with different cross sections locally indistinguishable? Does he simply mean topologically (ie. homeomorphic to one another)? Do they have the same chart?

Comment: @Pellenthor:  I believe he means as a manifold (i.e. diffeomorphic to one another).

Comment: This is very helpful again, thanks. In that case, would that make his second statement false (at least in the general case) since the Lie Bracket $[V_1, V_2]$  may be non-zero and thus the quadrilateral does not close?

Comment: No, I think that makes his second comment true.  Specifically, the point is that a pair of vector fields is equivalent to coordinate vector fields iff their Lie bracket is zero.   Thus, there are local obstructions to a pair of vector fields on one manifold being "the same" as a pair on another manifold, so these structures are *not* floppy.

Comment: I think I see. If I understand what you are saying correctly, the property that we can assign a couple of smooth vector fields on two copies of M_2 in two distinct ways (for example, one time with a vanishing Lie bracket and one time with a non-vanishing Lie bracket) means that we can distinguish geometrically between the two copies. Did I get the gist right?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right.

Comment: @Jason If you drop the condition ${\rm d}\omega=0$ but still assume that $\omega$ is non-degenerate, $\omega$ is called *almost-symplectic* --- this is the buzzword. There should be things about this around, but as far as I know, you can't really do much with that, it's a poor structure (Hamiltonian flows no longer preserve $\omega$, the Jacobi identity for the induced Poisson bracket fails, there are no torsionfree connections which parallelize $\omega$, it's a complete mess).

Comment: @IvoTerek and Jason. The integrability condition $d\omega = 0$ on the (almost-)symplectic structure leads to the existence of Darboux coordinates, much as the integrability condition of vanishing curvature for a Riemannian metric leads to the existence of 'Euclidean coordinates'. Hence indeed, integrability is responsible for the 'floppiness' of these structures. However local isometries of flat Riemannian manifolds are determined by their linearizations at any point, which is not true for symplectic manifolds. In this sense, symplectic manifolds are much more flexible than flat manifolds.